# Funny characters in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

This character (ï»¿) gets added to my javascript file. i am using visual studio 2010.
has any one come accross this issue?

This link explains my problem and a solution
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/144306.aspx
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters added are BOM characters,are not advised for utf-8. Visual studio by default saves javascript files with "Unicode(UTF-8 with signature)- Codepage 65001" encoding, this encoding adds the UTF-8 byte order mark at the beginning of the file. ie9 and chrome do not have a problem with it but firefox, opera and safari completely break....

so to fix it follow the solution in this document

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/144306.aspx and select the encoding option "Unicode(UTF-8 without signature)- Codepage 65001".

Hope this Helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

The js file is encoded as UTF-8 and has a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) identifying it as such.

This shouldn't be a problem so long as you serve the file up as UTF-8.

If the page doesn't already use a `meta` tag with the content type set to UTF-8, you can add this information to the script element, as described [here](http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/utf-8-javascript-files-298761.html):

```
<script src="js.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```